# Every velocity tool escape function working except url()?

Tags: apache, velocity

I can get $esc.html to work, but not $esc.url, it just comes up literal even though I follow example at: http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html
Interestingly enough, on that page the url() section's head is "$attrib.name" instead of url().

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me in Tools 2.0. Maybe you have old version?

```
$esc.url("bread & butter") = bread+%26+butter
```